# first child on a field set

Tags: html, css

I have 2 field sets inside a form tag called myform

I'm trying to get to the first fieldset. Now before the fieldsets there are other divs and p tags. 
I was trying this for the first fieldset and last

```
<myform>
  <div></div
  <p></p>
  <fieldset></fieldset>
  <div></div>
  <fieldset></fieldset>
</myform>

#myform fieldset{
// all round styles for the fieldset
}

    #myform:first-child fieldset{
// specific to the first field set
}

    #myform:last-child fieldset{
specific to the last filedset
}
```

Comment: I came across this problem too.. Haven't been able to solve it just yet though :/ I'll be checking this page!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your html is incorrect. `<myform></myform>` should be `<form id="myform"></form>`

and the proper selector is `#myform fieldset:first-of-type`

[This page](http://css-tricks.com/5762-pseudo-class-selectors/) is a good reference on how css pseudo-classes work

Comment: I'm pretty sure `first-child` will not work as the `fieldset` is not the first child of it´s parent element.

Comment: @jeroen: fieldset:first-child will select the fieldset element that is the first child of its parent element regardless of other elemnets that are in between as long as they are not fieldset.

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Thank you so much

Comment: Yup. My mistake. I need a break!

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your browser requirements, but to target all modern browsers, you can use:

```
#myform fieldset:first-of-type {
}
```

for the first `fieldset`.

**Edit:** You cannot use `:first-child` as the first `fieldset` is not the first child of it´s parent, see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child

Answer (score 0):

`<myform>` is not a valid HTML tag. Did you mean `<form id="myform" action="?">`?

Comment: this should really be a comment, not an answer

Comment: He used an `id` selector (albeit that might've been edited following your answer).

Comment: It was just a quick reference example. Not the correct code, sorry

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking you should do:

```
#myform fieldset:first-child {
    //specific to the first field set
}
```

As w3schools is saying:

> Select and style every p element that is the first child of its parent:

```
p:first-child
{ 
background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got the concept of first-child wrong. The first-child pseudo class select the element that is the first child of its parent elemnet. It doe snot select the first-child of the element. If you want to select the first filedset in the above code, simply use filedset:first-child or filedset:nth-child(1) and fieldset:last-child