# first-child issue on a fieldset

Tags: html, css

How do I get to the first fieldset. I tried this.

```
#enterAccountInfo fieldset:first-child{
}
```

also tried this:

```
#enterAccountInfo:first-child fieldset{
}
```

None of the above seemed to work.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <form id="enterAccountInfo">
        <fieldset class="even">
            <div class="centerWarpper">
                <h2 class="subtitle">blaa</h2>
         </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="odd">
            <div class="centerWarpper">
                <h2 class="subtitle">bllll</h2>
         </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="even">
            <div class="centerWarpper">
                <h2 class="subtitle">bllll</h2>
         </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="odd">
            <div class="centerWarpper">
                <h2 class="subtitle">bllll</h2>
         </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this post might be able to help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751413/first-child-on-a-field-set

Answer (score 1):

The first alternative is correct, and it works. If it does not, the problem is elsewhere, and you need to post more complete code, and identify the browser(s) tested. Check that you have that exact code, and use the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to check for any syntax errors.

The first alternative refers to the `fieldset` element that is the first child of the element with `id="enterAccountInfo"`, i.e. what you want.

The second alternative refers to any `fieldset` element that is inside the element with `id="enterAccountInfo"` if the latter is the first child of its parent (as it is here), so it selects all the `fieldset` elements here—nowt what you want.